How to encapsulate adding and removing of a temporary event handler in C#?
I 've got a section of code that may raise an event c.MyEvent (actually, lots of those). Before this section of code is executed, I want to add some Handler MyHandler to the event. The same handler shall be removed as soon as the section of code has completed. This can be achieved in a safe way as follows:
try
{
    c.MyEvent += MyHandler;
    // Section of code that may raise the event c.MyEvent ...
}
finally
{
    c.MyEvent -= MyHandler;
}

I do not like the above solution for the following reasons:

The exact same handler MyHandler has to be specified twice: Once when adding it to the event using += and the second time when removing it again using -=. This leaves opportunity for inconsistencies when accidentally specifying the wrong handler in one of those places. (DRY)
The use of try / finally leads to lots of code clutter around the interesting section of code.

I'm looking for a solution that avoids the above drawbacks as far as possible. I'm imagining some general method AddScopedEventHandler that

adds a specifyable handler (like MyHandler) to an arbitrary event (like c.MyEvent) and
returns an IDisposable that removes the same specified handler on dispose.

Using such a method, the above piece of code could be replaced with something like the following (more concise) piece of code (that should behave exactly like the above):
using (var scopedEventHandling = c.MyEvent.AddScopedEventHandler(MyHandler))
{
        // Section of code that may raise the event c.MyEvent ...
}

How can this (or something equivalent) be achieved?
Problems:

Events support only the operators += and -=. A direct extension method (as indicated with AddScopedEventHandler in the replacement code) will probably not be accepted by the compiler. Maybe, there needs to be some kind of wrapper for the event?
Even with access to the event delegate (by removing the event specifier from the declaration of MyEvent), there appears to be no method to change the internal list of handlers within the delegate.

Meanwhile, I found a working implementation of AddScopedEventHandler using reflection, but it is somewhat awkward in usage (Using it involves the repetition of c.):
using (var scopedEventHandling = c.AddScopedEventHandler(nameof(c.MyEvent), MyHandler))
{
        // Section of code that may raise the event c.MyEvent ...
}

I'm still looking for a better implementation avoiding the repetition and maybe not using reflection.
The following is a complete program showing the implementation based on reflection (see also: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMwmPl). The method TestExplicit shows an example for a temporary handler controlled by using += and -= explicitly. The method TestEncapsulated demonstrates the intended usage of AddScopedEventHandler:
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class C
{
    public event Action<int>? MyEvent;
    public void OnMyEvent(int v) => MyEvent?.Invoke(v);
}

public class Program
{
    private static void MyHandler(int v) { _Dummy = v; }
    private static int _Dummy = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Test explicit:");
        TestExplicit(new C());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Test encapsulated:");
        TestEncapsulated(new C());
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void TestExplicit(C c)
    {
        _Dummy = 1;
        try
        {
            c.MyEvent += MyHandler;
            c.OnMyEvent(2);
            System.Console.WriteLine($"  Expected 2: {_Dummy}");
        }
        finally
        {
            c.MyEvent -= MyHandler;
        }
        _Dummy = 3;
        c.OnMyEvent(4);
        System.Console.WriteLine($"  Expected 3: {_Dummy}");
    }

    static void TestEncapsulated(C c)
    {
        _Dummy = 1;
        using (var scopedEventHandling = c.AddScopedEventHandler(nameof(c.MyEvent), MyHandler))
        {
            c.OnMyEvent(2);
            System.Console.WriteLine($"  Expected 2: {_Dummy}");
        }
        _Dummy = 3;
        c.OnMyEvent(4);
        System.Console.WriteLine($"  Expected 3: {_Dummy}");
    }
}

public static class EventExtensions
{
    public static ScopedEventHandling<T> AddScopedEventHandler<T>(this T eventContainer, string eventName, Delegate handler) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var eventInfo = type.GetEvent(eventName);
        if (null == eventInfo)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"No event with name \"{eventName}\" found.", nameof(eventName));
        }
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(eventContainer, handler);
        return new ScopedEventHandling<T>(eventContainer, eventInfo, handler);
    }
}

public class ScopedEventHandling<T> : IDisposable
{
    public ScopedEventHandling(T eventContainer, EventInfo? eventInfo, Delegate handler)
    {
        _EventContainer = eventContainer;
        _EventInfo = eventInfo;
        _Handler = handler;
    }

    public T EventContainer => _EventContainer;
    public EventInfo? EventInfo => _EventInfo;
    public Delegate Handler => _Handler;

    #region IDisposable
    ~ScopedEventHandling()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_Disposed)
        {
            if ((null != _EventContainer) && (null != _EventInfo))
            {
                _EventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(_EventContainer, _Handler);
            }
            _Disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool _Disposed;
    #endregion IDisposable

    private readonly T _EventContainer;
    private readonly EventInfo? _EventInfo;
    private readonly Delegate _Handler;
}


Not really sure what you are asking, but do you mean something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTxUF8

@DavidG Thank you for your suggestion. It contains a class C configuring a specified handler for a contained event on construction. What I am looking for is a concise way to add and remove a temporary handler for an event of an object of an arbitrary class C. I will update my question to add more precision.

Did you see Reactive Extensions (RX)?

@Alexander Petrov Thank for the hint to https://reactivex.io/ but I don't think it is applicable here. ReactiveX appears to be concerned more with high-level parallel event orchestration rather than with the low level events as those declared in a class. My question is concerned with the latter.

It is really not clear what you are asking for. I would really appreciate less code with more intention. For example, could you only provide code which demonstrates how exactly would you want to use the AddScopedEventHandler method ? I see you are talking about event properties, but event properties only expose += and -= api. It's quite confusing to orient in your question.

@Tomas Tillmann I've edited my question in order to provide more intention.
